# Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.postgresql.Driver' for connect URL postgres://username:password@localhost:5432/dbname

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-roo

I have deployed two Spring roo application on Tomcat 7 server both have database connection while hitting any service of application I am getting below exception

```
Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.postgresql.Driver' for connect URL 'postgres://username:password@localhost:5432/db'
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:278)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1437)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcServicesImpl.java:279)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
```

Please find below database base configuration

Application 1

application-Context.xml

```
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
    <property name="testOnReturn" value="true"/>
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000"/>
    <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3"/>
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT version();"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Application 1. Database.properties

```
database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
database.url=jdbc\:postgresql\://localhost\:5432/db
database.username=username
database.password=password
```

Application 2

application-Context.xml

```
<bean class="java.net.URI" id="dbUrl">
    <constructor-arg value="postgres://username:password@localhost:5432/db"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="#{ 'jdbc:postgresql://' + @dbUrl.getHost() + ':' + @dbUrl.getPort() + @dbUrl.getPath() }"/>
    <property name="username" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[0] }"/>
    <property name="password" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[1] }"/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
    <property name="testOnReturn" value="true"/>
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000"/>
    <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3"/>
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT version();"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<util:properties id="regex.properties" location="classpath:META-INF/spring/regex.properties"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Please advice how can I resolve my Problem..

Comment: Look at the connect URLs you have in your question.

Comment: Do you have the postgres library in your classpath?

Comment: Yes, f1sh, My Application 2 (old) is able to connect with the database, while 1st is not

Comment: @Kayaman, edited the urls it was typo

Comment: @Mayur thats not the question. Your app cannot find the postgres driver class. So it's not in the classpath of your application.

Comment: @f1sh It cannot *create* the driver, because the connect URL is wrong.

Comment: @Kayaman that's not what the exception says.

Comment: @f1sh That's exactly what the exception says.

Comment: @f1sh, it is web application on Unix platform, I have posrgres driver class in application's lib folder, where else should it be present ?

Answer (score 4):

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"     destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db" />
    <property name="user" value="user" />
    <property name="password" value="pass" />
    <!-- pool sizing -->
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="3" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="6" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="25" />
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="3" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="0" />
</bean>
```

I used this and it works

Comment: Exactly. When the connect URL is in the proper form, it works.

Comment: @Mayur Where did you edit it, because it's still wrong in all the places I'm looking at.